# Julia: broadcast results in array of arrays

Tags: arrays, julia

This seems basic enough that I expected someone already asked this, but I couldn't find it.

When I use broadcasting the naive way I'm getting an array of arrays when I would like to get a two-dimensional array. For example, this function

```
function onehotencode(n, domain_size)
    return [ n == k ? 1 : 0 for k in 1:domain_size ]
end
```

When I run

```
onehotencode.([1,2,3,4], 10)
```

I get

```
4-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Instead, I would like to get

```
4x10 Array{Int64,2}:
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function returns vectors so they are collected as a vector of vectors. Either write:

```
permutedims(reduce(hcat, onehotencode.([1,2,3,4], 10)))
```

which reuses your code and gets you what you want (but is not very efficient), or simply write:

```
.==([1,2,3,4], (1:10)')
```

or

```
.==([1,2,3,4], hcat(1:10...))
```

If you want to get an `Int` (not `Bool`) then write `Int.(.==([1,2,3,4], hcat(1:10...)))`.

`==` can be replaced by any function of your choice that works on *scalars*, for example:

```
julia> f(x,y) = (x,y)
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f.([1,2,3,4], hcat(1:10...))
4×10 Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},2}:
 (1, 1)  (1, 2)  (1, 3)  (1, 4)  (1, 5)  (1, 6)  (1, 7)  (1, 8)  (1, 9)  (1, 10)
 (2, 1)  (2, 2)  (2, 3)  (2, 4)  (2, 5)  (2, 6)  (2, 7)  (2, 8)  (2, 9)  (2, 10)
 (3, 1)  (3, 2)  (3, 3)  (3, 4)  (3, 5)  (3, 6)  (3, 7)  (3, 8)  (3, 9)  (3, 10)
 (4, 1)  (4, 2)  (4, 3)  (4, 4)  (4, 5)  (4, 6)  (4, 7)  (4, 8)  (4, 9)  (4, 10)
```

In general a rule, that I find useful in practice in Julia is to write functions that work on scalars and then use broadcasting or other higher-order components of the language to work on them.

**EDIT**

Your function takes scalars, but actually expands them internally and returns a `Vector`. So conceptually your function is something like:

```
function onehotencode(n, domain_range)
    return [ n == k ? 1 : 0 for k in domain_range]
end
```

although it is hidden because you pass a scalar. Therefore you are allowed to write `onehotencode.([1,2,3,4], hcat(1:10...))` with your `onehotencode` implementation but the return value is treated as an entry in a cell of the resulting `Matrix` (and this is clearly not what you want).

If you define your function as:

```
function onehotencode(n, v)
    return n == v ? 1 : 0
end
```

i.e. taking scalars and returning a scalar (or more precisely returning a "single entry" in the expected resulting `Matrix`, as technically it does not have to be a scalar) then all works as expected:

```
julia> onehotencode.([1,2,3,4], hcat(1:10...))
4×10 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

So in summary the function should: get scalars as arguments and return a scalar (and again the word scalar is a simplification - both in arguments and return value these can be anything that is considered as a single entry - simply scalars in both cases are a most common use case).

Comment: Your code works, thank you very much. But isn't my question precisely one instance of "write functions that work on scalars and then use broadcasting" not working out well? I had a function that worked on scalars (e.g. `onehotencode(4, 10)`) but now I have to use different code for the vector case (`.==([1,2,3,4], hcat(1:10...))`. Also you say "== can be replaced by any function of your choice that works on scalars" but in reality `onehotencode.([1,2,3,4], hcat(1:10...))` doesn't give me what I want.

Comment: I will elaborate on this in an answer.

Comment: I see what's going on now. Thanks for the clarification :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! Mind explaining what `'` does in `.==([1,2,3,4], (1:10)')` ?

Comment: `(1:10)'` is adjoint of `1:10` so in this case is is an object that has 1 row and 10 columns. Since `[1, 2, 4, 5]` has 4 rows and 1 column the result is all combinations of the input and has 4 rows and 10 columns.